# cURL post to start Jenkins with parameters doesn't work

Tags: curl, jenkins

I have the following command to start the Jenkins job with parameters, according to this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build. However, the value of pkgId is not visible in Jenkins job.

```
D:\Jirong\Jenkins>curl -X Post "http://localhost:8000/job/Test/job/Test_
Parametized/buildWithParameters?token=5e4ca21c566fe4ac5cf8dfe3ba55be8c&pkgId=123
4413225"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the auth token in the header of the HTTP post request...

Try like this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic <replace_auth_token_here>" -X POST "http://localhost:8000/job/Test/job/Test_
Parametized/buildWithParameters?YOUR_JOB_PARAM_NAME=YOUR_JOB_PARAM_VALUE"
```

Comment: C:\Users\Alex>curl -H \"Authorization: Basic 5e4ca21c566fe4ac5cf8dfe3ba55be8c\"
-X Post "http://localhost:8000/job/Test/job/Test_Parametized/buildWithParameters
?pkgId=123"
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Basic
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 5e4ca21c566fe4ac5cf8dfe3ba55be8c"

Comment: Sorry remove all the blackslashes before the double quotes

Comment: This works but the variable $pkgId is still not set: C:\Users\Alex>curl -H "Authorization Basic 5e4ca21c566fe4ac5cf8dfe3ba55be8c" -X Post "localhost:8000
/job/Test/job/Test_Parametized/buildWithParameters?pkgId=123"

Comment: @JirongHu is pkgId the name of the parameter? Normally those are defined all caps, like this JOB_PARAMETER

Comment: IMHO, you can **add notes in your answer**: ***1)*** `remove all the blackslashes before the double quotes` and ***2)*** `the name of the parameters normally those are defined all caps, like this JOB_PARAMETER`